# How to display one aspect of a C# Model List in Javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Ok, so I currently have a List that I can store names for a card game.  I can currently use this list to create a javascript array.  Ideally, I want to store the card's name and its value.  I created:

```
    public class CardValue
{
    string name {get;set;}
    int value {get;set;}
    public CardValue(string Name, int Value)
    {
        this.name = Name;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

But I am not sure how to sometimes just access the list of names, and other times the name and value.  I know a fair amount of c#, but am fairly new to both javascript and MVC.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

in MVC you can create Model like this:

```
public class CardValue
{
     public string name {get;set;}
     public int value {get;set;}
}
```

you do not need to do the setter again in the model itself

if you need to convert the model to javascript array

two possible approaches:

1. create an javascript array and then iterate through the model list and push to the array
2. using Json.encode(Model) and then using the jquery parseJson to create the array